# Ошибка мутирующих таблиц в триггере (ORA-04091), когда запросе участвуют таблицы Master-Detail

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Помогите исправить триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OPTT.TBDR_PROTOCOL
AFTER DELETE
ON OPTT.PROTOCOL 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
begin
   delete from RULE 
   where  RULE.OWNERENTITYGUID = 'tblJBLJOL4TFBAHLBEWZMLSHXYGMM'--this table idx
   and    RULE.OWNERPID = :old.ID
   and    RULE.CLASSGUID = 'acl4ZWIAW7W45H4HKTIPF6W6IQZTA';

   exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
       null;    
end;
/
```

Где, `RULE` - master таблица, а `PROTOCOL` - любая таблица, **не является** для `RULE` detail таблицей

При выполнении получается ошибка:

> ORA-04091: table OPTT.TESTCASESTEPRULE is mutating, trigger/function
>   may not see it

Где `OPTT.TESTCASESTEPRULE` - является detail таблицей для `RULE`, в триггере таблица `PTT.TESTCASESTEPRULE` **не участвует** в запросах.

Причем, `delete from RULE` можно спокойно заменить на `select * from RULE`, ошибка останется такая же.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: Не надо использовать триггер там, где в этом нет никакой необходимости.

Удалите триггер, перенесите логику из триггера в то место, где вызывается DML выражение, которое приводит к срабатыванию триггера. Создайте там  процедуру или функцию, если эта логика используется не единожды в приложении.

---

Перед тем как создать триггер, надо убедится в его необходимости ознакомившись с рекомендациями по применению триггеров, например в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS723).

Само появление ошибки - `ORA-04091: table is mutating`, говорит, что допущена логическая ошибка в дизайне кода и БД вынуждена прибегнуть к защите от возможной потери целостности данных в мульти-пользовательской среде.

Выше изложеное не раз обсуждалось на различных ресурсах, например, цитирую Тома Кайта на [спроси Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866):

> My personal opinion -- when I hit a mutating table error, I've got a serious fatal flaw in my logic.
>
> Have you considered the multi-user implications in your logic? Two people inserting at the same time (about the same time). What happens then??? Neither will see eachothers work, neither will block -- both will think "ah hah, I am first"...
>
> anyway, you can do too much work in triggers, this may well be that time -- there is nothing wrong with doing things in a more straightforward fashion (eg: using a stored procedure to implement your transaction)

PS Кроме того, не возникнет ситуация как в вопросе, где с наибольшей долей вероятности, поиск ошибки идёт не в том триггере, который эту ошибку действительно вызвал.

Comment: Ошибка действительно была не в этом месте

Answer (score 2):

Тут сложно ответить, не видя реальных связей между таблицами. Как вариант обхода такой мутации - написать второй триггер типа statement. 
В первом триггере, который построчный - инициализировать пакетную переменную как :old.ID, во втором, который statement - вызывать процедуру удаления, используя пакетную переменную, установленную на первом шаге. 
Естественно, ограничение - удалять записи из rule можно только по одной.

PS. Exception тут лишний, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Причина ошибки указана в сообщении об ошибке

> ORA-04091: table OPTT.TESTCASESTEPRULE is mutating, trigger/function
> may not see it

Таблицы `OPTT.TESTCASESTEPRULE` нет в приведенном в вопросе триггере, то есть **ошибку вызвал другой триггер**. Какой, можно быстро узнать запросом

```
SELECT trigger_name, trigger_type, triggering_event   
FROM all_triggers tr
WHERE table_owner='OPTT'
AND table_name='TESTCASESTEPRULE'
```