# Ошибка при изменении таблицы - "ORA-04091: таблица изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Ошибка возникает, если пытаюсь в таблице `RegHotelRoom` поменять значение `Status` на 1.

```
One error saving changes to table "REDMARK"."REGHOTELROOM":
Row 3: ORA-04098: триггер 'MARK.LOG_ERRORS' недействителен и вызвал сбой при перепроверке достоверности
ORA-04091: таблица REDMARK.REGHOTELROOM изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это
ORA-06512: на  "REDMARK.DROP_TABLE_AFTER_INSERT", line 2
ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'REDMARK.DROP_TABLE_AFTER_INSERT'
ORA-06512: на  "REDMARK.ARHIVE", line 3
ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'REDMARK.ARHIVE'
```

Таблица `RegHotelRoom`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные внутри таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Триггер на `Update`:

```
create or replace trigger Arhive after UPDATE ON REGHOTELROOM FOR each ROW
BEGIN
    if (:new.STATUS = 1) THEN
        insert into reghotelroomarhive (ID_REGHOTELROOM, ID_NOMER,
            ID_CLIENT, DATEOFSTART, DATEOFEND) 
        values ( :old.ID_REGHOTELROOM, :old.ID_NOMER,
            :old.ID_CLIENT, :old.DATEOFSTART, :old.DATEOFEND);
    end if;
END;
```

Таблица `RegHotelRoomArhive`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Триггер на удаление записи из `RegHotelRoom`:

```
create or replace trigger DROP_TABLE_AFTER_INSERT  
    after insert ON reghotelroomarhive FOR each ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM REGHOTELROOM WHERE (ID_REGHOTELROOM = :new.ID_REGHOTELROOM);
END;
```

Comment: А какой смысл всей этой операции? Изменив  Status на 1, вы тут же пытаетесь эту запись удалить. Так работать не будет.

Comment: @0xdb При изменении значения запись должна добавиться в таблицу RegHotelRoomArhive и удалиться из таблицы RegHotelRoom, что бы не засорять таблицу RegHotelRoom

Comment: @0xdb а что можно в этом случае сделать?

Comment: Пересмотреть дизайн приложения. Какой смысл изменять запись, если вы собираетесь её тут же удалить?

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо, помогли.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок в будующем, посмотрите [эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471474/217579). Там постарался доходчиво описать, когда нужны триггеры, а когда надо отказаться от них вообще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменить запись чтобы её тут же удалить, не имеет никакого смысла.

Вместо изменения просто удалите запись в таблице `REGHOTELROOM`. Для архивации удалённых записей можно воспользоватесь таким триггером:

```
create or replace trigger Arhive after delete on REGHOTELROOM FOR each ROW
begin
    insert into reghotelroomarhive (ID_REGHOTELROOM, ID_NOMER,
        ID_CLIENT, DATEOFSTART, DATEOFEND) 
    values ( :old.ID_REGHOTELROOM, :old.ID_NOMER,
        :old.ID_CLIENT, :old.DATEOFSTART, :old.DATEOFEND);
end;
```