# Ошибка при попытке удалит строку - ORA-04091: таблица изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_INFO(
  ID VARCHAR2(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE USER_HISTORY(
  ID VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO USER_INFO(ID, NAME) VALUES('111', 'VLAD');
INSERT INTO USER_INFO(ID, NAME) VALUES('222', 'ANNA');
INSERT INTO USER_INFO(ID, NAME) VALUES('333', 'VIKA');
```

Если удалить запись в таблице `USER_INFO`, то должен срабатывать триггер и запись должна вставится в `USER_HISTORY`.

Для этого был написан такой триггер:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REMOME_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON USER_INFO FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  user_name VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN 
     SELECT NAME INTO user_name FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID=:old.ID;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('user_name:');
END;
/
```

Ожидаю, что при удалении какой-нибудь стоки из таблицы `USER_INFO` этот триггер сработает, но при таком запросе:

```
DELETE FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID='222';
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
DELETE FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID='222'
Error report -
ORA-04091: таблица USER_INFO изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это
ORA-06512: на  "REMOME_TRIGGER", line 4
ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'REMOME_TRIGGER'
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен триггер? Вы провели поиск по этому сайту [ORA-04091](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-04091)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя в построчном триггере обращаться к таблице, которая изменяется.

Но собственно, обращаться к ней и не нужно:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REMOME_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON USER_INFO FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
     insert into user_history values (:old.id, :old.name);  
END;
/

delete from user_info
/
3 rows deleted.

select * from user_history
/
ID       NAME    
-------- --------
111      VLAD    
222      ANNA    
333      VIKA
```

---

PS в [связанном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471474/217579) подробнно обсуждались причины этой ошибки.

Более точный перевод текста ошибки:

> ORA-04091: table XY is mutating, trigger/function
> may not see it

таблица XY находится в процессе изменения (мутирует), триггер/функция может не увидеть эти изменения.