# Как написать триггер, который бы изменял значения в таблице, на основе значений из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Имеются три таблицы: Заказы (`Orders`), Количество товаров в заказе (`AmountIn`), Количество товаров на складе (`AmountOut`). Собственно сами таблицы:

`Orders`:

| ID | DateStart | DateEnd | Status | ShopId | WarehouseId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | 0 | 1 | 1 |

`AmountIn`:

| ID | Amount | GoodsId | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 | 1 |

`AmountOut`:

| ID | Amount | GoodsId | WarehouseId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 1 |

Требуется написать триггер, который при изменении статуса заказа, с 0 (не выполнен), на 1 (выполнен) удалял из таблицы `AmountOut`, количество товаров указанное в таблице `AmountIn`, учитывая склад, и после удалял весь заказ в таблице `AmountIn`. А при изменении статуса с 0 на 2 (отменён), просто удалял информацию о заказе в таблице `AmountIn`.

Например, для описанных таблицы результат будет таковым, что в таблице `AmountOut`, `Amount` будет равен 80, запись о заказе в таблице `AmountIn` будет удалена.

Сейчас имеется вот такой запрос:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_status_update
AFTER UPDATE
    ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (UPDATING (orders.status)) THEN
       BEGIN
          IF (:new.orders.status = 1) THEN
              -- Удаление из таблицы AmountOut отсутствует 
              DELETE FROM AMOUNT_IN a WHERE a.orders_id = :old.orders_id;
          ELSIF (:new.orders.status = 2) THEN
              DELETE FROM AMOUNT_IN a WHERE a.orders_id = :old.orders_id;
          END IF;
       END;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Странные таблицы, обычно есть сущности товар, склад, заказ, отдел сборки заказа, движение со склада или на склад это операция с физическим перемещением товара, при чем тут заказ... Накладная товар принят от поставщика размещен на складе 1, странные таблицы, вы в триггере в комментарии пишите одну таблицу а удаляете записи из другой таблицы. Использование операции delete не очень хорошая идея в принципе. Правильней было бы другая реализация через свойства признаки или флажки и update, ну не суть... Можете чуть больше информации, что не получается?

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев, вместо комментария в коде должно быть удаление количества заказанных товаров со склада, то есть из таблицы AmountOut. Не совсем понятно как это реализовать, то есть не понятно, как удалить из таблицы AmountOut то количество товаров, которое указано в таблице AmountIn по каждому товару для заказа, статус которого был изменён.

Comment: соглашусь с тем, что триггеров лучше избегать, мне все еще не понятна проблема, если вам нужно сделать select amount перед удалением, что вас смущает? Объявите переменную получите в нее нужный amount и уменьшайте используя update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Триггер тут не нужен. Создайте процедуру и используйте её для изменения статуса:

```
create or replace procedure setOrderStatus (id int, newstatus int) is
    WarehouseId int;
    GoodsId int;
    Amount int;
begin 
    update orders set status = newstatus 
    where id = setOrderStatus.id
    returning WarehouseId into WarehouseId;
    
    delete from amountin a where a.orderid = setOrderStatus.id
    returning Amount, GoodsId  into Amount, GoodsId;
    
    if (newstatus = 1) then
        update amountout set Amount = Amount - setOrderStatus.Amount
        where GoodsId     = setOrderStatus.GoodsId 
        and   WarehouseId = setOrderStatus.WarehouseId;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Результат ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=284bdd35b2b65555756b13e18524ff38)):

```
exec setOrderStatus (1, 1)

select * from AmountOut union all
select * from AmountIn
/
        ID     AMOUNT    GOODSID WAREHOUSEID
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1         80          1           1
```

Ознакомтесь [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471474), особенно по ссылке на оф.документацию в ответе, когда рекокомендуется и имеет смысл использовать триггер. Если всё там приведённое не убедитeльно, то решение с триггером выглядит так:

```
create or replace trigger orders_status_update
after update of status on orders for each row
when (old.status = 0 and new.status in (1,2))  
begin
    <<my>> declare
        GoodsId int;
        Amount int;
    begin
        delete from amountin a where a.orderid = :new.id
        returning Amount, GoodsId into my.Amount, my.GoodsId;
        if (:new.status = 1) then
            update amountout set Amount = Amount - my.Amount
            where GoodsId     = my.GoodsId 
            and   WarehouseId = :new.WarehouseId;
        end if;
    end;    
end;
/
```